# Using a structure in a recursive function (referenced structure)

Tags: c, recursion, structure

I'm having problems understanding how to write code that solves the following problem: I have a structure containing a 2D-array. Then I have a recursive function that take a pointer to the structure as an argument and I want the recursive function to be able to manipulate the structure sent, not a local copy.

The struct is initialized in the function initStruct, where memory for the 2D-array is allocated. The recursive function builds up an array and at a specific point calls a function to insert it into the structure's array.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int** spBasis(int);
void mpBasis(int**, int, int, int, int, int, int, int*, struct mpBasis *, int, int);
void initMpBasis(struct mpBasis *, int, int);
void insertMpState(struct mpBasis *, int *);

struct mpBasis {
    int** basis;
    int size;
    int capacity;
};

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    char maxE[256];
    char noParticles[256];
    char P[256];
    char M[256];
    FILE *fp;
    int **spStates;
    struct mpBasis *mp;
    int mpState[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    printf("Input max e for sp states, no of particles, parity (1 for odd and 0 for even) and magnetic projection: ");

    gets(maxE);
    gets(noParticles);
    gets(P);
    gets(M);
    spStates = spBasis(atoi(maxE));
    fp = fopen("spStates.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(fp, "E\tj\tl\tm\n");
    for (a = 0; a < 330; a++) {
        fprintf(fp, "State %d: ", a+1);
        for (b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
            fprintf(fp, "%d\t", spStates[a][b]);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }

    mp = malloc(sizeof(struct mpBasis));
    initMpBasis(mp, 5449, 6);

    for (c = 0; c < 5449; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < 6; d++) {
            fprintf(fp, "%d: %d\t", c, mp->basis[c][d]);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }

    printf("%p\n", (void*) mp);

    printf("hello 3");
    mpBasis(spStates, 0, atoi(maxE), 0, atoi(M), 0, atoi(P), mpState, mp, 0, 0); 

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int** spBasis(int maxE) {
    int c;
    int i, j, k, l;
    int q = 0;
    int** spStates;

    spStates = (int**)malloc(330 * sizeof(int *));
    for (c = 0; c < 330; c++) {
        spStates[c] = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= maxE; i++) {
        for (j = i % 2; j <= i; j += 2) {
            for (k = -(2 * j  + 1); k <= (2 * j + 1); k += 2) {
                spStates[q][0] = i;
                spStates[q][1] = j;
                spStates[q][2] = 2 * j + 1;
                spStates[q][3] = k;
                q += 1;
            }
            for (l = -(2 * j - 1); l <= (2 * j - 1); l += 2) {
                spStates[q][0] = i;
                spStates[q][1] = j;
                spStates[q][2] = 2 * j - 1;
                spStates[q][3] = l;
                q += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return spStates;
}

void mpBasis(int** spStates, int e, int maxE, int m, int M, int l, 
    int P, int * mpState, struct mpBasis *mpB, int position, int lastSpState) {
    int i;

    for (i = lastSpState; i < 330; i++) {
        if (e > maxE) {
            break;
        } else if (position == 5) {
            if (m == M && l % 2 == P) {
                 insertMpState(mpB, mpState);
                 break;
             }
        } else {
             // add spState to mpState and make the recursive call for the next position
            mpState[position] = i;
            mpBasis(spStates, e + spStates[i][0], maxE, m + spStates[i][3], M, 
                l + spStates[i][1], P, mpState, mpB, position+1, i);
        }
    }
}

void initMpBasis(struct mpBasis *a, int initialSize, int sizeY) {
    int c;
    a->basis = (int **)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int*));
    for (c = 0; c < initialSize; c++) {
        a->basis[c] = (int *) malloc(sizeY * sizeof(int));
    }
    a->size = 0;
    a->capacity = initialSize;
}

void insertMpState(struct mpBasis *a, int* mpState) {
    /*if (a->size == a->capacity) {
        a->size *= 2;
        a->basis = (int **)realloc(a->basis, a->size * sizeof(int));
    }*/
    a->basis[a->size++] = mpState;
}
```

Added all the code.

The problem is that after the recursive function has been called, the "basis" array in structure mpBasis still only contains random values, i.e. the mpBasis function hasn't done anything with it. Am I passing the mp argument by value here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what exactly is the question??

Comment: What *is* the problem? What's the expected behaviour? Show a minimal code example that showcases the problem(s).

Comment: Not sure what else I should do. There is no real code example that shows it. The array just doesn't change after the call to the recursive function which make a call to the insertInformation function which explicitly inserts values into the structure.

Comment: @Peter: sure there is. Just take your real code, throw away **everything** not directly relevant to the problem, and then post that.

Comment: @Oli: Added the code that is important.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to compile with warnings enabled. Eg if you are using GCC you can use option **-Wall** -Wextra.

**EDIT**:

(previous listing of >20 errors removed)

Ok, since you are using Visual Studio, enable warnings like this:

- Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
- Select C/C++.
- On the General property page, modify the Warning Level to /W4

Comment: Thank you for answering. I extracted the code that might affect the problem and removed everything else, including variable declarations etc. The code compiles fine with not warnings under Visual Studio, so I'm not sure.

Comment: you did not activate the warnings in visual studio then. please look up how to enable them.

Comment: Well, I mean there are no warnings for the whole code. The parts I included in the question are only parts of it. I have gotten warnings earlier in studio so I think they should be on. I just pasted the parts that I thought might affect the problem. I think it's about pointers (could be very wrong of course, since I'm a noob at C)

Comment: Edited my answer. Try it out, seeing warnings make you a better programmer! Then if you have enabled W4 and still not seeing errors please post the whole code so that we can compile it.

Comment: Oh I see, you were right. I compiled with /W4 and there were some additional warnings, but nothing critical as far as I can tell. Added all the code now.

Comment: Ok thanks, compiles now. I am trying to figure out what is wrong but i dont know what acceptable input-values would be, eg i tried 100[ENTER]10[ENTER]0[ENTER]1[ENTER] and it just crashes.

Comment: Sorry about that, totally forgot! Correct input values are 8[ENTER]6[ENTER]1[ENTER]0[ENTER] because I haven't completely figured out how write an array that resizes itself when it gets full. Thank you for sticking with me!

Comment: Ok, insertMpState never gets called (at least not for this input). (position==5) is true a lot of times but (m == M && l % 2 == P) is never true.

Comment: Nice catch. It should be (m / 2 == M) && (l %2 == P) in the condition, a mistake by me. If I print out the pointers in both the main function and in the mpBasis function they have different addresses when they should be the same.

Comment: Ok, now we have an infinite recursion of mpBasis_f()'s.

Comment: Sorry i mean mpBasis(). I only added the _f (and _s) to distinguish between the struct and the function.

Comment: You mean for the absolute last calls to mpBasis_f, when i = 327 or something like that?

Comment: i is 329 and then begins again starting at 2.